# Joining mysql join two table MAX(value)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

```
my question is how to get max share by news id where created_at is today?
```

try with 
    SELECT Max(shares.id),facebook FROM shares GROUP BY shares.id ORDER BY facebook DESC LIMIT 20;

```
select * from shares;

+-------+----------+
| id    | facebook |
+-------+----------+
| 1     |      584 |
| 1     |      610 |
| 2     |      354 |
| 2     |      360 |
| 2     |      467 |
| 1     |     1324 |
| 2     |      924 |
+-------+----------+

select * from news;

+----+-------------------------------+------------+
| id | url_address                   | created_at |
+----+-------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | http://www.google.com         | 1417496667 |
|  2 | http://www.facebook.com       | 1417491832 |
+----+-------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: There is no question. Please put more effort into your questions. So other people will put effort in their answer.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT s.id, SUM(s.facebook)
FROM shares s 
INNER JOIN news n ON s.id = n.id 
WHERE n.created_at = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()) 
GROUP BY s.id 
ORDER BY SUM(s.facebook) DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: how do I get where news is today